# disable default zoom in feature on input controls in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

when user clicks on input controls like input text of text area, the webview zooms in by default,

Can we control this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use it.You can set zoom on webview according to your requirement.

```
WebView webView=(WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.link4_view);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(50);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.racquetime.com/terms");
            webView.zoomIn();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply... but when I click on input control in webview, the view zooms in, I just want to avoid the zoom in feature here....